# Job type(Full Time , Part Time) detection with Machine learning model in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp

I have a dataset of jobs where I have columns "Title" ,"Description" , "City" etc. and "Best Jobs" column. Output of the dataset is "Best Jobs" where I have two outputs(Yes , No) Yes mean jobs are part time and No , mean job is full time. I want to train any Machine learning model. Firstly I want to train the Model X or feature columns will be Title , Description etc. and Label will be "Best Jobs". But I do not know how to train the Model on string columns. Please help me in this.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os, sys
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

df = pd.read_csv("machinelearning-new-best-gar-jobs.csv", engine = 'python',encoding='mac_roman')
df.head()\
```

[image]

```
df['Job description'].replace('  ', np.nan, inplace=True) df=df.dropna(subset=['Job description']) df.isnull().sum()
```

[image]

Then I will convert the Label (BestJobs) to integer 1 and 0

```
df['BestJobs'] = (df['BestJobs']=='Yes').astype(int)  # changing yes to 1 and no to 0 print(df['BestJobs'].value_counts())
```

[image]

I want to know which Model should I apply to get it done.

Comment: What *exactly* is your issue and your *question*? What is the "*next Model technique*"?

Comment: Hello @desertnaut I have a dataset of jobs where I have columns "Title" ,"Description" , "City" etc and "BestJobs" column. Output of the dataset is "BestJobs" where I have two outputs(Yes , No) Yes mean jobs are part time and No , mean job is full time. I want to train any Machine learning model. Firstly I want to train the Model X or feature columns will be Title , Description etc and Label will be "BestJobs". But I do not know how to train the Model on string columns. Please help me in this.

Comment: I am afraid this is not a *programming* question, hence it is off-topic here and rightfully closed now; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably can only use two columns "Job description" and "Best Job" to train the model. Then it becomes a Text Classification problem, like classifying movie reviews as either positive or negative. Then you can preprocess the job description text and use a neural network to train your model.

The basic idea is that you may only need a few required features to train your model instead of processing all of the feature data you got. You can refer to this blog https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/text-preprocessing-for-nlp-natural-language-processing-beginners-to-master-fd82dfecf95 (Text Preprocessing for NLP).

Hope it is helpful for you!